# Setting Up Gulp - Cannot find module 'gulp'

Tags: gulp

I am new to Gulp and am following a [tutorial](https://travismaynard.com/writing/getting-started-with-gulp). I get to the final step and run `gulp` in my project file but I receive an error saying that the module 'gulp' cannot be found. I have verified that I have installed gulp. Both CLI (on a side note, what does CLI mean?) and Local versions are 3.9.1. I am wondering what am I doing incorrectly?

gulpfile.js:

```
// Include gulp
var gulp = require('gulp');

// Include Our Plugins
var jshint = require('gulp-jshint');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');

// Lint Task
gulp.task('lint', function() {
    return gulp.src('js/*.js')
        .pipe(jshint())
        .pipe(jshint.reporter('default'));
});

// Concatenate & Minify JS
gulp.task('scripts', function() {
    return gulp.src('js/*.js')
        .pipe(concat('all.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'))
        .pipe(rename('all.min.js'))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/js'));
});

// Watch Files For Changes
gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch('js/*.js', ['lint', 'scripts']);
});

// Default Task
gulp.task('default', ['lint', 'scripts', 'watch']);
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "gulp",
  "version": "3.9.1",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.0",
    "gulp-jshint": "^2.0.1",
    "gulp-rename": "^1.2.2",
    "gulp-uglify": "^1.5.4",
    "jshint": "^2.9.2"
  }
}
```

file structure:

```
|-- gulpfile.js
|-- package.json
|-- node_modules
|   |-- .bin
|   |-- gulp-concat
|   |-- gulp-jshint
|   |-- gulp-rename
|   |-- gulp-uglify
|   |-- jshint
```

error:

[image: command line gulp error]

Answer (score 0):

Issue is because my project folder is named 'gulp'. Changing the project folder to anything else other than 'gulp' solved the issue. https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/11772

Answer (score 0):

Install Gulp in your devDependencies

```
npm install --save-dev gulp
```

Go to Your DIrectory , which is

```
D:\xampp\htdocs\test\gulp>npm install --save-dev gulp
```

And Hit Enter